# How to wait for response from modal window before continuing using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, modal-dialog

I have a python program in which I've created a few custom modal windows that are children of a top level tkinter window. An example of such a window is below, but I have other, more complicated ones. What I would like to do, but cannot determine how, is to have somewhere that I call this and wait for a response. I've tried something like below, it fails to create the window

```
modal = ModalWindow(tk.Tk(), 'Title', 'Text')
while modal.choice is None:
    pass
if modal.choice == 'Yes':
    # Do Something
```

What is the appropriate way to handle this type of thing?

**Custom Modal Window Example**

```
class ModalWindow(object):

    def __init__(self, root, title, text):
        self.choice = None

        # Setup the window
        self.modalWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.modalWindow.title(title)
        self.modalWindow.resizable(False, False)

        # Setup the widgets in the window
        label = ttk.Label(self.modalWindow, text = text, font = '-size 10')
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2)

        but = ttk.Button(self.modalWindow, text = 'Yes', command = self.choiceYes)
        but.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew', padx = 2, pady = 5)

        but = ttk.Button(self.modalWindow, text = 'No', command = self.choiceNo)
        but.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew', padx = 2, pady = 5)

        self.modalWindow.rowconfigure(1, minsize = 40)

    def choiceYes(self):
        self.choice = 'Yes'
        self.modalWindow.destroy()

    def choiceNo(self):
        self.choice = 'No'
        self.modalWindow.destroy()
```

Answer (score 3):

After some further digging, I found my own answer. The following does what I want. The function `wait_window` accepts a tkinter window and pauses until that window has been closed.

```
root = tk.Tk()
modal = ModalWindow(root, 'Title', 'Text')
root.wait_window(modal.modalWindow)
if modal.choice == 'Yes':
    # Do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

I am missing something fundamental here.  If the window is application-modal, you're forced to wait: there's nothing programmatic to be done.  If you're trying to wait for an event that transpires in a window belonging to ANOTHER application, you're hosed unless you write some thorny OLE code (I assume Windows here, as UNIX way of doing things would never lead one eve to consider such a solution component).

Comment: But the thing is, you're not. With the Modal Window class I wrote, it brings up the GUI it it's own thread and that GUI waits, but the code that called it continues to execute. The issue comes from the fact that the while loop right after causes the GUI to not completely come up. Run the code yourself and you'll see.